# the equation $\cos (\sin x)=x$ has exactly one solution in $[0,\pi/2]$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Prove or disprove the equation $\cos (\sin x)=x$ has **exactly** one solution in $[0,\pi/2]$.

First let , $f(x)=\cos(\sin x)-x$. Then , $f(0)=1>0$ and $f(\pi/2)=\cos 1-\pi/2<0$. So by Bolzano's theorem , $f$ has **at least** one zero in $(0,\pi/2)$.

But I am unable to check whether $f$ has exactly one zero OR NOT ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

First, if it has a solution, it's in $[0,1]$. It's also very easy to prove that $f(x)=\cos(\sin(x))-x$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,1]$ (since $f'<0$) and thus injective. Therefore, you got your result.

Comment: How the solution is in $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: $0\leq \cos(\sin(x))\leq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Therefore, if $x>1$, $\cos(\sin(x))\neq x$.

Comment: @@Surb ) I think your $f(x)$ will be $\cos(\sin x)-x$

Comment: yes of course :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\eqalign{
  & f'(x) =  - \cos x\sin (\sin x) - 1  \cr 
  & f'(x) < 0 \cr} $$